# Can null be inserted into Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, design-patterns, null-object-pattern

I actively use caching in my ASP.NET web site.

Though, some objects requested from db are really absent. For instance, I'm checking if there is a `Discount` for the particular product by looking record with `ProductId=@ProductId` in `ProductsDiscount` table. Absence of the record means no discount.

Do you think it is a good idea to put `null` discount objects into Cache?

Or I would better invent something better (using null-object pattern, for instance). In fact, I don't really like idea to start using null-object pattern as it will require a lot of redesign that I would like to avoid at least right now.

Thanks. Any thoughts are welcome.

P.S. In fact, I can't even put null object into Cache, when I try to call:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("name...", null);
```

i receive:

> Value cannot be null.

P.P.S. Why MSDN tells nothing about this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your case, you could use `DBNull.Value` as the 'no data' marker:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("name...", DBNull.Value);
```

Comment: Yes, I'll need to use 'something else' as a no data marker... don't see better option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't put a null in the cache, what would be the point? If the discount is a numeric value then the lack of a discount (null in your table) really indicates a discount of 0% - so why not store a 0?

Comment: Ok, we can argue about "how to store discounts", but that is only a particular case. I'm interested more in the solution to know that request to DB was already done (and there no record in DB) and there are no purpose to make another request.

Comment: In that case I'd store something like a placeholder to indicate a null value, or that the action has been performed.

Comment: Storing null is a valid use case if I am caching a parameter that isn't used for that customer. Without the ability to cache null, I have to perform the query every time to determine that there is no value. I ended up using Gonzalo's suggestion of storing DBNull.Value in the cache class and silently converting that to/from a regular null.